# How to formulate MYSQL Query

Tags: mysql, sql, join

Suppose I have three tables: `Customer`, `TV`, `Radio`

The `Customer` table contains attributes: `customerID`, `First name`, `Last name`

The `TV` table contains attributes: `customerID`, `year`, `numTVsBought`

The `Radio` table contains attributes, `customerID`, `year`, `numRadiosBought`

So in the TV and Radio table, a specific customerID can appear multiple times, corresponding to different years.

Now I want to obtain a table that contains CustomerID, TotalTVsBought, TotalRadiosBought

When I do:

```
SELECT CustomerID, SUM(numTVsBought), SUM(numRadiosBought)
FROM Customer
LEFT JOIN TV on Customer.customerID = TV.customerID LEFT JOIN Radio on Customer.customerID = Radio.customerID
GROUP BY Customer.customerID;
```

I get the right values for numTVsBought, but numRadiosBought is overstated. Am I joining the tables the wrong way?

Comment: If you're still struggling see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the way that you join your tables, is that for each TV, you will add Radios as well.
Try this:

```
SELECT c.customerId, ifnull(tv_count.counter, 0) as totalTvsBought, ifnull(radio_count.counter,0) as totalRadiosBought
FROM customer c
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT customerId, SUM(*) as counter
    FROM TV 
    GROUP BY customerId) tv_count
        ON tv_count.customerId = c.customerId
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT customerId, SUM(*) as counter
    FROM Radio 
    GROUP BY customerId) radio_count
        ON radio_count.customerId = c.customerId
```

When joining multiple tables you need to think like the computer; he'll join all records before doing the count.

Comment: Thanks this worked. If I wanted to then get a count for the number of customers who have bought both a larger amount of TVs and Radios than the average amount of TVs and Radios bought per customer, how would I do that?

Comment: I don't think that something like that would be performant if you want it in one query; you would end up in adding subqueries; better just first select the averages, and then you can add them to the above query to select on those that have a totalTvsBought > $averageTvsBought or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server we can simply achieve it with the Common Table Expressions (CTE)

```
WITH TBL1 AS 
(
        SELECT C.CustID AS CUST_ID, SUM(T.NoOfTVsBought) AS TOTAL_T From Customer C
        LEFT JOIN TVs T
        ON C.CustID = T.CustID
        GROUP BY C.CustID
)
SELECT CUST_ID, TOTAL_T, TBL2.TOTAL_Radios FROM TBL1
LEFT JOIN(
SELECT C.CustID, SUM(R.NoOfRadBought) AS TOTAL_Radios From Customer C
LEFT JOIN Radios R
ON C.CustID = R.CustID
GROUP BY C.CustID) AS TBL2
ON TBL1.CUST_ID = TBL2.CustID
```